# Autogenerate unit test stubs on Android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I am creating the unit test for some legacy android codes.

Currently i need to manually create the unit test for each class/method in test/java.

Is there an automated way to auto generate all the test stubs? ideally from the Android studio IDE? (similar to how parasoft can autogenerate empty test stubs for C++ classes and methods).

I am using robolectric on Android studio 1.2.1

Comment: hey did you ever find a way to do this

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast, unfortunately no.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this: Right-click the class name. `Go To -> Test`. Select the function, Done.

[image]